# Higher ramification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, ramification

Let $K/L/M$ be finite Galois function field extensions and let $P|Q|S$ be places of the corresponding function fields. Write $G_i(\cdot|\cdot)$ for the $i$-th ramification groups.

One can easily show that the canonical projection $Gal(M/K) \rightarrow Gal(L/K)$ projects $G_i(S|P)$ into $G_i(Q|P)$ surjectively for $i=-1,0$.

What about the higher $i$'s?

In general, this projection induces an embedding 
$G_i(S|P)/G_i(S|Q) \rightarrow  G_i(Q|P)$ and
this has to be an isomorphism for $i=-1,0$ because the cardinalities of the left and right side are the same.
But this holds only since the ramification groups are the decompositon and inertia groups and their cardinalities are $ef(\cdot|\cdot)$ and $e(\cdot|\cdot)$, which again satisfy the multiplicative transitivity rule.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of Herbrand''s upper ramification indices?

Comment: This doesn't work in general. This is exactly the reason for the introduction of the higher number system. We can define a new ramification group $G^i$ in a slightly convoluted way, where now $i\in \mathbb R$. These ramification groups behave well under projections.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer: Never heard of it. At Mathmo123: Thank you very much. This answers my question completely.